# In how many ways can 8 similar rings be worn in five fingers of a hand?

Tags: combinatorics

Provided that a finger may not contain more than one ring.However a finger may be empty.

Comment: Welcome to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question body should be self containing. What are "similar rings"? Identical rings where you can't tell them apart? or Non-identical rings which will result in a different way of wearing if exchanged between two fingers?

Comment: Um, if you don't have enough fingers for all the rings, and you're not allowed to reuse fingers, then there'd be _zero_ ways to wear them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one finger may contain more than one ring you can consider the following model. Let x be one ring. | separates every finger.

x x |x x| x |x x| x

Thus on finger one you have 2 rings,on finger two 2 rings and so on. You have 8 (x=rings)+4 (|=separating the fingers)=12 elements. Choosing four | determines the arrangement of the 8 rings on the 5 fingers. Hence the number of combinations is $\binom{12}{4}=495$.

Answer (score 0):

9*8*7*6*5

9 possibilities for the first finger, ect.

Now, one has to only multiply it with the binomial coefficient i guess. (or not?)

Edit: if the rings are the same, which can be that way, since you ask "similar rings" then just $2^5$ possibilities

Answer (score 0):

As the rings are same and a finger can have either a single ring or can go without ring hence there is only one way to select a ring from 8 (because all rings are same).

So your question reduces to - How many ways five fingers can have a single or no ring which would be -

(all five fingers are filled)+(4 fingers are filled)+(3 fingers are filled)+(2 fingers are filled)+(1 finger are filled)+(all are blank)
=1+(5C4)+(5C3)+(5C2)+5+1
=32

Other approach to how many ways five fingers can have a single or no ring which would be -
$2^5$
because either a finger can have a ring or not. And there are such five fingers.